# Cannot access folder after creating it dynamically

Tags: python

I cannot access a folder called 'book' (via programs) and its files after creating it dynamically. I am doing some image binarizations with ocropy (see at the end). When I list files and folder with python's os.listdir, it shows the folder, but as I try to change the folder permissions like (or try to access that folder via programs it says `cannot access 'book': No such file or directory`.

```
subprocess.call(['chmod', '-R', '+w', 'book'])
```

I do not understand why it is happening. Please share some thoughts if you have faced similar problems.

with the following code, it lists the 'book' folder, however, and I can access it via windows 7 GUI

```
files = os.listdir('folder')
for file in files:
    print file
```

Binarization code that produces 'book' folder dynamically

```
def binarization(imagefile):
    args = ["python", "ocropus-nlbin", "-n", imagefile, "-o book"]
    print "opening process"
    proc = Popen(args, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    print "launching it"
    ret = proc.communicate()

    code = proc.returncode
    if code == 0:
        print "success!"
    if code != 0:
        if code == 2:
            raise PythonException, "File not found"
        if code == -11:
            raise PythonException, "Language code invalid: "+ret[1]
        else:
            raise PythonException, ret[1]
```

Comment: I'm confused... you `os.listdir('folder')` but then show that you are outputing to `"-o book" ... where did `'folder'` go?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `chmod -R +w folder/book`?

Answer (score 0):

`os.listdir` lists the files and folders in a directory. If you want to use the files/folders, you have to prepend the directory to them

```
$ mkdir folder
$ mkdir folder/book
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.listdir('folder')
['book']
>>> os.path.exists('book')
False
>>> os.path.exists(os.path.join('folder', 'book'))
True
```

Comment: I am getting false by os.path.exists(os.path.join('folder', 'book')), and it is strange

Comment: That is strange. `os.listdir('folder')` returns `['book']` but `os.path.exists` returns false?

Comment: yes, it is and it is very annoying because I am struck and need to finish my code asap

Comment: @AnayBose "I am stuck and need to finish my code ASAP." If you're not prepared for this to be the situation nearly every day of your employment, you may want to consider a different career.

Comment: I agree with your comments and perspective. Yes, I should be more patient